# Program to format every media in c++

Tags: c++, windows-xp, format, drive

**Problem:**
I'm trying to write a program that formats any type of media.
So far I've managed to format Hard disk partitions, flash memories, SDRAM, RDX.
But there's this last type of media (DVD-RAM) I need to format. My program fails to format this media.
I'm using the `FormatEx` function in `fmifs.dll`. I had absolutely no idea how to use this function Except for its name and that it resides in `fmifs.dll`. with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13252858/279982) I managed to find a [simple program](http://pete.akeo.ie/2012/04/chkdskx-and-formatx-by-mark-russinovich.html) that uses this library. Yet still it doesn't give complete information about how to use it.

**What I've tried:**
I'm looking for a full documentation about `FormatEx`, its parameters, and exactly what values each parameter can take.
I tried searching on google and MSDN. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa819439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is what I found. First of all this isn't the function I'm working with. But even putting that aside there's not enough information on how to use the function (Like which headers/libraries to use).

**EDIT:**
I don't have to use `FormatEx` if there's an alternative to use please tell.

**EDIT 2:**
During further test I noticed I can format the DVD-RAM if it's initial file system is "FAT32". But if it's any of "UDF" revisions formatting fails.
Moreover, quick format fails instantly and regular formatting fails after 90+ % progress. But when I check disk content after it's all the same. As if format did not even attempt.

Comment: Google *fmifs russinovich* ; http://pete.akeo.ie/2012/04/chkdskx-and-formatx-by-mark-russinovich.html

Comment: The comment and answer by Alex K. point you to a copy of the source code for FormatEx by Mark Russinovich. The code pretty much documents the fmifs.dll FormatEx function. The function itself has never been documented.

Comment: Have you tried passing "UDF" or "FAT32" as the format argument to FormatEx to format DVD-RAM?

Comment: @Anthill, I am passing "FAT32". Testing different things, I noticed I can format the DVD-RAM when it is already formatted as "FAT32", but not when its initial format is "UDF". I guess this is a limitation of `FormatEx`.

Comment: What's your quickformat argument when attempting to format to UDF? Are you passing FALSE?

Comment: @Anthill, passing in `true`.

Comment: Have you tried passing false?

Comment: It has started formatting, I'll let you know if it succeeds.

Comment: This took a while and after it gets around 100% (maybe even 100% itself, I wasn't paying attention all the time) it fails to format the drive.

Answer (score 7):

It was written by Mark Russinovich (Sysinternals) who made the source available, there are plenty of copies knocking about if you Google for *fmifs russinovich*.

http://pete.akeo.ie/2012/04/chkdskx-and-formatx-by-mark-russinovich.html

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the only stumbling block you have is formatting to UDF. FormatEx in fmfifs.dll, is a shim (or helper) utility which dispatches the formatting task to a lower level driver as part of Microsoft's installable file system infrastructure ([IFS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548137%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). IFS basically allows Microsoft to add support for new file systems.

In the case of UDF the corresponding library would UUDF.DLL (this convention holds for other filesystems, for instance NTFS would be handled by UNTFS.DLL, UFAT.DLL ,and so on). Is this dll present on your Windows XP system?

Looking at the exports of UUDF.dll using depends.exe I see support for various functions including the infamous FormatEx. FormatEx seems to be cdecl and (looking at the dissassembly) expects 16 bytes of arguments (probably 4 arguments). While it would be handy to be able to call the function directly it is not documented anywhere and it would be a pain figuring the arguments out. Moreover I'd assume that fmifs.dll would do the right thing if it could.

UDF supports several revisions ([see OSTA specification](http://www.osta.org/specs/)) - your problem may well be that your version of UUDF.dll on WinXP has problems with the version of UDF your DVD-RAM is formatted with.

What you *could* do instead would be to use the [DeviceIOControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function with the [IOCTL_SCSCI_PASSHTHROUGH_DIRECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) control code which would enable you to directly talk to the device. Formatting a DVD-RAM using SCSI/MMC (Multi-Media-Commands) should be possible - look up a description of the [FORMAT_UNIT command](http://storagesecrets.org/2009/01/scsiformatunit/). The MMC commands are specified in http://www.t10.org/drafts.htm#MMC_Family T10 working drafts - they are a pain to get hold of but I believe one can download copies as a guest after registering.

If the easy (fmifs.dll) way is not working for you, you'll have to do it the hard way or find a third-party dll to assist you.

**Update:**

Looking on MSDN, the IMAPI2 (Image Mastering API) is supported from XP Service Pack 2. An alternative to using fmifs.dll would be to use the IDicFormat2Erase interface's EraseMedia() function to erase the disc and then to use the IFileSystemImage interface's FileSystemsToCreate() function to format to UDF. Potentially simpler than the DeviceIOControl route.

Since I've never done this I decided to put a quick example together. It's quick & dirty and untested (created a UDF rev 2.50 filesystem on a DVD-RW and that's it) but it's a starting point (Visual Studio 2012):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <imapi2.h>
#include <imapi2fs.h>
#include <imapi2error.h>
#include <imapi2fserror.h>
#include <comdef.h>


void ShowComError(HRESULT hr)
{

    LPWSTR lpMsgBuf;
    DWORD ret;

    std::cout << "Failed - HRESULT = 0x" << std::hex << hr << std::endl;
    ret = FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE,
        GetModuleHandle(TEXT("imapi2.dll")),
        hr,
        0,
        (LPWSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL );

    if(ret)
    {
        std::wcout << L"HRESULT: " << lpMsgBuf << std::endl;
        LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    }

}

int main()
{
    IDiscMaster2* ppMaster = NULL;
    IDiscRecorder2* ppRecorder = NULL;
    IDiscFormat2Erase* ppFormat2 = NULL;
    IDiscFormat2Data* ppFormat2Data = NULL;
    IFileSystemImage* ppFileImage = NULL;
    IStream* fs = NULL;
    IFileSystemImageResult* res = NULL;

    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

    BSTR clientName = SysAllocStringLen(L"TestBurner", lstrlen(L"TestBurner"));
    SAFEARRAY* multi = NULL; // multi-sessions

    hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MsftDiscMaster2),
        NULL,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        __uuidof(IDiscMaster2),
        (void **) &ppMaster);

    if (FAILED(hr)) 
    {
        ShowComError(hr);
        //nothing-wrong-with-a-goto-when-its-heart's-in-the-right-place ;)
        goto Clean_Up; 
    }       


    hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MsftDiscRecorder2),
        NULL,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        __uuidof(IDiscRecorder2),
        (void **) &ppRecorder);

    if (FAILED(hr)) 
    {
        ShowComError(hr);
        goto Clean_Up;
    }

    hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MsftDiscFormat2Erase), 
        NULL, 
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
        __uuidof(IDiscFormat2Erase), 
        (void**) &ppFormat2);

    if(FAILED(hr))
    {
        ShowComError(hr);
        goto Clean_Up;
    }

    hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MsftDiscFormat2Data), 
        NULL, 
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
        __uuidof(IDiscFormat2Data), 
        (void**) &ppFormat2Data);

    if(FAILED(hr))
    {
        ShowComError(hr);
        goto Clean_Up;
    }

    hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MsftFileSystemImage),
        NULL,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        __uuidof(IFileSystemImage),
        (void**) &ppFileImage);

    if(FAILED(hr))
    {
        ShowComError(hr);
        goto Clean_Up;
    }


    // got here - get the optical drives
    LONG countDevices;
    hr = ppMaster->get_Count(&countDevices);
    if(FAILED(hr))
    {
        ShowComError(hr);
        goto Clean_Up;
    }

    VARIANT_BOOL supported;
    hr = ppMaster->get_IsSupportedEnvironment(&supported);
    // check if it's supported - if yes we use it to format 
    // and then break out...
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr) && supported == VARIANT_TRUE)
    {
        BSTR deviceName;
        for(LONG i = 0; i < countDevices; i++)
        {
            hr = ppMaster->get_Item(i, &deviceName);
            if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                std::wcout << L"Using: " << deviceName << std::endl;
                hr = ppRecorder->InitializeDiscRecorder(deviceName);
                if(FAILED(hr)) goto Clean_Up;

                hr =  ppRecorder->AcquireExclusiveAccess(VARIANT_TRUE, clientName);
                if(FAILED(hr))
                {
                    ShowComError(hr);
                    goto Clean_Up;
                }

                hr = ppFormat2->put_Recorder(ppRecorder);
                if(FAILED(hr)) goto Clean_Up;

                // need to set client_name before erasing

                hr = ppFormat2->put_ClientName(clientName);
                if(FAILED(hr)) ShowComError(hr);
                //SysFreeString(clientName);


                BSTR owner = NULL;
                hr = ppRecorder->get_ExclusiveAccessOwner(&owner);
                if(FAILED(hr))
                {
                    ShowComError(hr);
                    goto Clean_Up;
                }
                if(owner)
                {
                    std::wcout << owner << std::endl;
                    SysFreeString(owner);
                }

                // erase the disc
                hr = ppFormat2->put_FullErase(VARIANT_TRUE);
                if(FAILED(hr)) goto Clean_Up;

                hr = ppFormat2->EraseMedia();
                if(FAILED(hr))
                {
                    ShowComError(hr); // Need to pull eventual errors out of imapi2error omitted...
                    //goto Clean_Up;
                }

                hr = ppFormat2Data->put_Recorder(ppRecorder);
                if(FAILED(hr))
                {
                    ShowComError(hr);
                    goto Clean_Up;
                }

                hr = ppFormat2Data->put_ClientName(clientName);
                if(FAILED(hr)) ShowComError(hr);


                hr = ppFormat2->IsCurrentMediaSupported(ppRecorder, &supported);
                if(FAILED(hr))
                {
                    ShowComError(hr);
                    goto Clean_Up;
                }

                VARIANT_BOOL blank;
                hr = ppFormat2Data->get_MediaHeuristicallyBlank(&blank);
                if(blank == VARIANT_FALSE)
                {
                    hr = ppFormat2Data->get_MultisessionInterfaces(&multi);
                    if(FAILED(hr))
                    {
                        ShowComError(hr);
                        goto Clean_Up;
                    }
                }

                /*hr = ppFileImage->ChooseImageDefaults(ppRecorder);
                if(FAILED(hr))
                {
                    ShowComError(hr);
                    goto Clean_Up;
                }*/


                FsiFileSystems imported = FsiFileSystemNone;
                if(multi)
                {
                    hr = ppFileImage->put_MultisessionInterfaces(multi);
                    if(FAILED(hr))
                    {
                        ShowComError(hr);
                    }

                    hr = ppFileImage->ImportFileSystem(&imported);
                }

                if(imported == FsiFileSystemNone || imported == FsiFileSystemUnknown)
                {
                    imported = FsiFileSystemUDF;
                    // ask for UDF revision 2.50
                    hr = ppFileImage->put_UDFRevision(0x250);
                    if(FAILED(hr))
                    {
                        ShowComError(hr);
                    }

                }
                hr = ppFileImage->put_FileSystemsToCreate(imported);
                if(FAILED(hr))
                {
                    ShowComError(hr);
                }


                hr = ppFileImage->CreateResultImage(&res);
                if(FAILED(hr))
                {
                    ShowComError(hr);
                    goto Clean_Up;
                }

                hr = res->get_ImageStream(&fs);
                if(FAILED(hr))
                {
                    ShowComError(hr);
                    goto Clean_Up;
                }

                hr = ppFormat2Data->put_ForceOverwrite(VARIANT_TRUE);
                if(FAILED(hr))
                {
                    ShowComError(hr);
                    goto Clean_Up;
                }

                hr = ppFormat2Data->Write(fs);
                if(FAILED(hr))
                {
                    ShowComError(hr);
                    goto Clean_Up;
                }


                hr = ppRecorder->EjectMedia();
                break;
            }

        }

    }


    // clean up
Clean_Up:
    if(res) res->Release();
    if(fs) fs->Release();
    if(multi) SafeArrayDestroy(multi);
    if(clientName) SysFreeString(clientName);
    if(ppFileImage) ppFileImage->Release();
    if(ppFormat2Data) ppFormat2Data->Release();
    if(ppFormat2) ppFormat2->Release();
    if(ppRecorder) ppRecorder->Release();

    if(ppMaster) ppMaster->Release();

    CoUninitialize();

    /**/
    std::cout << "Press any key to continue..." << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have the DVD-RAM driver installed and using the format option in windows gets the job done neatly and quickly. Yet I couldn't find `uudf.dll` using windows search. Either it's using some other dll or it's hidden somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the sample cod. I'll check it out as soon as I get the chance.